# Unable to build ODK Aggregate

Tags: aggregate, odk

I am Unable to build ODK Aggregate. Getting this error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project aggregate-gae: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   org.opendatakit:aggregate-gae:war:1.0: The following artifacts could
>   not be reso lved: org.opendatakit:aggregate-src:jar:latest,
>   org.opendatakit:odk-gae-it-settings:jar:latest,
>   com.googlecode.gwt-google-maps-v3:gwt-google-maps-v3:jar:snapshot,
>   com.google.gwt.go ogle-apis:gwt-visualization:jar:1.1.1,
>   org.javarosa:javarosa-libraries:jar:2013-09-30,
>   org.opendatakit:odk-httpclient-gae:jar:1.1,
>   org.opendatakit:odk-tomcatutil:jar:1.0, org.openi
>   d4java:openid4java-nodeps:jar:0.9.6.662.odk-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:
>   jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.springframework.security:spring-security-openid:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.
>   springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.3.odk-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failure to find org.opendatakit:aggregate-src:jar:latest in
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the loc al repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have not installed the jar files required.
please read the instruction on;
http://aggregate.opendatakit.googlecode.com/hg/CONFIGURE.txt

Read it line by line. it might be wise to run maven from the terminal